# Checking valid values for overriden variables in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What I'm interested in doing is checking the value of a variable that's been overridden on the command-line has one of several valid values. Specifically, I have part of my makefile that looks like so:

```
ifndef BUILD
    BUILD ::= release
endif

# Set flags for $(CC), based on the value of $(BUILD) 
CFLAGS ::= -Wall -pthread -std=c17 -I./src/include
CFLAGS.debug ::= -g
CFLAGS.release ::= -O3
CFLAGS ::= $(CFLAGS.$(BUILD)) $(CFLAGS)
```

My goal is to be able to run something like `make BUILD=debug` without having to write a seperate debug target and adding a bunch of mess to my recipies.

What I want is a way to do something like `$(warn Invalid BUILD option)` if something like `make BUILD=production` is specified. Is there a better/more idiomatic way of doing this than just nesting a bunch of `ifneq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, something like this will work:

```
BUILD ?= release
OK_BUILDS := debug release

$(if $(filter $(BUILD),$(OK_BUILDS)),,$(warn Invalid BUILD option: $(BUILD))
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about using `$(filter ...)`! Just out of curiosity, is there a way I could conditionally do `override BUILD ::= release` to set a default if something invalid was specified? I haven't used `$(if ...)` before, so I'm not 100% sure of the rules on its syntax, and the manual reads ambiguously to me.

Comment: In that case I would use something like `ifneq ($(filter $(BUILD),$(OK_BUILDS)),)` / `override ...` / `endif` rather than the `if`-function.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't write my makefile this way though.  IMO it's a bad idea to forcibly fix someone's mistake unless you are 100% sure you know what they really meant.  If they give the wrong value, tell them about it and let them fix it to be correct.  You could enhance the error message to print the legal values (`$(OK_BUILDS)`) of course.

Comment: Hmm, you make a good point. I'll probably just have it be a `$(error ...)` instead to cancel the build w/a printout of valid `BUILD` values. Thanks again for your help! :)